# Ionic 3- Change iframe content size depending on screen size

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic2, ionic3

I have news section in my app, I'm displaying news using iframe tag from some website, I want change iframe content size depending on the mobile screen size.

**News.html code:**

```
<iframe width="300" height="470" src="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/"></iframe>
```

**My screens looks like this:**
[image: News screen]

Comment: Use `width="100%" height="100%"` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can style an iframe as you would any other element on the page with CSS.  If you use viewport (vw/vh/vmin/vmax) values, you can scale both the height and the width proportionally to the device/window size.  Below I've added an id to the iframe:

```
<iframe width="300" height="470" src="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/" id="newsframe"></iframe>
```

In your CSS, you could add rules targeting the element id:

```
#newsframe {
  //set the height to 100% of the viewport less the height of the header
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);

  //set the width to 100% of the viewport width
  width: 100vw; 

  //remove border, padding, margin
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you not give any **width** size it takes full width.